# Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted, SQL server agent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I execute the following statements on the management studio perfectly, with out any problem.

```
Execute sp_addlinkedserver 'remoteservername'


execute sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'remoteservername', @locallogin = N'sa', @useself = N'False', 
@rmtuser = N'remoteuserlogin', @rmtpassword = N'remoteuserpwd'


select * into local_table_bkup FROM [remoteservername].remotedb.dbo.table_name
```

But when I try to use them in the `SQL server` agent job schedule, the following query does not work in `T-SQL` and throws the error

> Executed as user: dbo. Access to the remote server is denied because
>   the current security context is not trusted. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error
>   15274)

```
select * into local_table_bkup FROM [remoteservername].remotedb.dbo.table_name
```

Could some one please help me out?

I have loogged in as user `sa` .I am running the job on my local server.

Comment: Solved by right clicking the linked server for options and by ticking the checkbox for 'impersonate option' in security option.

Comment: Can you please put your solution as an answer and accept it?

Comment: not the problem , but please don't use the 'sa' user. It shouldn't even be enabled on a properly locked down system!

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
USE [master]

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'LINK_SERVER', @locallogin = N'sa', @useself = N'False', @rmtuser = N'sa', @rmtpassword = N'123456'

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'**LINK_SERVER**', @locallogin = **NULL** , @useself = N'**False**'

GO
```